# What's the most efficient way to change Tower Bux (TB) into Coins?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

If I'm impatient with the sales in my Tiny Tower, I can use different methods to turn precious Tower Bux into coins:

- Sell stock from a business
- Exchange at bank
- Upgrading businesses to sell more stuff

Tower Bux for Coins, which method of changing Tower Bux into coins will earn the most Tower Bux?

Comment: I dumped all my tower bucks into the faster elevators, now THAT is impatience.

Comment: Do you want to 'cheat' ?

Comment: I don't want to fiddle with the clock or hack any files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick-selling:

It costs 1TB to sell 600 units of an item (regardless of value - 1, 2, or 3 coins) - so this will net you a maximum of 1800 coins per TB if you are selling the top value item.

[Trading Tower Bux](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Bank_%28game%29#Bank):

> Option 1: The cheapest option is the exchange of 1 Tower Bux for 250
>   coins. Let's represent the words "Tower Bux" as "TB" in an effort to
>   save time.  250 coins / 1TB = 250 coins. Therefore, 1TB= 250 coins in
>   the first option. It's an OK investment, but as a persistent investor,
>   you can find a better option.
>
> Option 2: The second option is the exchange of 5 Tower Bux for 1,500
>   coins. That would mean that 1 Tower Bux, or 1TB, equals 300 coins. 
>   1,500 coins / 5TB = 300 coins, therefore 1TB = 300 coins. The second
>   option would seem to be the better investment, because in Option 2,
>   one Bux equals a whole 50 coins more than in Option 1.
>
> Option 3: Now let's move on to Option 3, which is the exchange of 20
>   Tower Bux for 20,000 coins. If I do the math; 20,000 coins / 20TB =
>   1,000 coins, therefore 1TB = 1,000 coins.  Huge difference, right?
>   That shoots the worth of a Tower Bux up from 300 coins to 1,000 coins,
>   making Option 3 the best investment so far.
>
> Option 4: This final and most costly exchange is 50 Tower Bux for
>   100,000 coins. Here's the math: 100,000 coins / 50TB = 2,000 TB.
>   Therefore, 1TB equals a whopping 2,000 coins, which would be the
>   obvious best investment. Considering that the original value of a
>   Tower Bux was 250 coins and now it's 2,000 coins, the final value of
>   one Tower Bux is 8 TIMES MORE than the original investment!

[Upgrading floors](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Strategy/Currency#Floor_Upgrades):

> The profit per upgrade is 765 coins/ stock-sale cycle with all 3 dream
>   jobs filled. It's roughly 8 stock-sell cycles,
>   which for most floors will take under 1 day each cycle (at best), or
>   a week to 8 days (at worst) to be making extra compared to buying
>   coins. It would appear to be a good investment to upgrade floors,
>   especially where you have dream jobbers for that floor.

Each upgrade of a floor costs you 3 TB, so you gain roughly 255 coins/sale cycle per TB spent.

**Summary**

If you want fast money, saving TB and taking them to the bank nets you the most bang for your TB instantly, if you save to the top-level of a 50 TB trade. Upgrading floors is probably your second best bet, if you want more money over time. Quick selling is good for a quick cash infusion.